# How to create a half oval in the top of the screen in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

is there a way to create an oval on top of the screen? I tried using RenderBox, but feel it is not a right solution.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use *CustomPainter* and play with curves:

[image]

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            CustomPaint(
              painter: ShapesPainter(),
              child: Container(height: 300),
            ),
            Text('Text')
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

const double _kCurveHeight = 35;

class ShapesPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final p = Path();
    p.lineTo(0, size.height - _kCurveHeight);
    p.relativeQuadraticBezierTo(size.width / 2, 2 * _kCurveHeight, size.width, 0);
    p.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    p.close();

    canvas.drawPath(p, Paint()..color = Colors.red);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, very great response. by the way is it possible to add the one, I updated just right now? It it is more like rounded line, but not a circle.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to draw a half oval in flutter is using the CustomPainter.

```
Container(
  child: CustomPaint( // Widget
    painter: PainterDetails(), // CustomPainterClass
  ),
),

// CustomPainterClass
class PainterDetails extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // here is where you will draw the half oval using canvas Paint class and Path class
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

You can use the quadraticBezierTo function to draw a curve.